# How to add Validators in Vaadin 8?

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin8

In Vaadin 7 there was an addValidator function, but in Vaadin 8 it does not exist.

Vaadin 7 Example:

```
   TextField user = new TextField("User:");
   user.setRequired(true);
   user.setInputPrompt("Your username");
   user.addValidator(new NullValidator("Username can't be empty", false));
   user.setInvalidAllowed(false);
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I found the answer here: [Whats New](https://vaadin.com/framework/whatsnew)

Example:

```
new Binder<Person>().forField(tf)
    .withValidator(str -> str.length() == 4, "Must be 4 chars")
    .withConverter(new StringToIntegerConverter("Must be Integer"))
    .withValidator(integer -> integer.equals(2017), "Wrong date")
    .bind(Person::getBirthYear, Person::setBirthYear);
```

[image]

Comment: What if you don't have a binder due to creating a dynamic form?

Answer (score 4):

The [accepted Answer by Diego D](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42492167/642706) looks correct. That code looks to be taken from this very brief (3 minutes) but *very* helpful video published by the Vaadin company, [Type safe validation before and after converters](https://youtu.be/ErtGCPFtGrE). Shows the new Vaadin 8 approach to validation. I'll add some notes, show expanded syntax, and provide full example code for a full working app.

### Validator + Binder

One big difference in Vaadin 8 is that **validators require the [use of a binder](https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/datamodel/datamodel-forms.html)**. In the old days, you attached a validator to a field, but now in Vaadin 8 you attach a validator only to a binder. The Vaadin team recognizes that for some simple situations this requirement of a binder may prove annoying, but for the most part they sensibly expect situations needing validation are quite likely also doing binding. A very logical re-think, I believe. Discussed in another Vaadin company video, [Webinar: What's new in Vaadin 8?](https://youtu.be/RBHEpYx0MMg?t=46m42s).

## Validation & converters

We define two different validators, one to be called before a converter converts the user’s data-entry and another to be called after conversion. So the order of the fluent-style `withValidator` and `withConverter` method calls is key to correct behavior here. Of course `beforeConversion` and `afterConversion` are poor names for validator objects, but are done so to make clear the intent of running before or after converter in this demo.

## Lambda synax optional

One validator uses conventional Java code style overriding a method. The other validator uses Lambda syntax. Watch the video and see [the Diego D Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42492167/642706) for code further simplified with single-line Lambda arguments.

```
package com.example.valapp;

import com.vaadin.annotations.Theme;
import com.vaadin.annotations.VaadinServletConfiguration;
import com.vaadin.data.Binder;
import com.vaadin.data.ValidationResult;
import com.vaadin.data.Validator;
import com.vaadin.data.ValueContext;
import com.vaadin.data.converter.StringToIntegerConverter;
import com.vaadin.server.VaadinRequest;
import com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet;
import com.vaadin.ui.*;

import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;


/**
 * This UI is the application entry point. A UI may either represent a browser window
 * (or tab) or some part of a html page where a Vaadin application is embedded.
 * <p>
 * The UI is initialized using {@link #init(VaadinRequest)}. This method is intended to be
 * overridden to add component to the user interface and initialize non-component functionality.
 */
@Theme ( "mytheme" )
public class MyUI extends UI {

    @Override
    protected void init ( final VaadinRequest vaadinRequest ) {

        final TextField tf = new TextField ( "Enter year of birth:" );

        Validator<String> beforeConversion = new Validator < String > ( ) {
            @Override
            public ValidationResult apply ( String s, ValueContext valueContext ) {
               if(s.length ()!= 4) {
                   return  ValidationResult.error ( "Year must consist of 4 digits" );
               } else {
                   return  ValidationResult.ok () ;
               }
            }
        } ;

        Validator<Integer> afterConversion = Validator.from ( value -> value.equals ( 2017 ), "Wrong year." );

        new Binder < Person > ( )
                .forField ( tf )
                .withValidator ( beforeConversion )
                .withConverter ( new StringToIntegerConverter ( "Input must be Integer" ) )
                .withValidator ( afterConversion )
                .bind ( Person:: getYearOfBirth, Person:: setYearOfBirth );

        Button button = new Button ( "Tell me" );
        button.addClickListener ( event -> Notification.show("This is the caption", "This is the description", Notification.Type.HUMANIZED_MESSAGE) );

        setContent ( new VerticalLayout ( tf  , button ) );
    }

    @WebServlet ( urlPatterns = "/*", name = "MyUIServlet", asyncSupported = true )
    @VaadinServletConfiguration ( ui = MyUI.class, productionMode = false )
    public static class MyUIServlet extends VaadinServlet {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> What if you don't have a binder due to creating a dynamic form?

Vaadin 8.1 supports removing the binder for a field which supports dynamic forms.
If you make a field invisible then remove the binder for that field. Re-add the binder when you make the field visible.