# Customize DateTimeField in Vaadin 8

Tags: vaadin8

In DateTimeField component, it displays both date (year, month, day) and hour (hour, minute, second). 
Now i don't want to get date. Any idea to only allow to show and get time ( hour:minute:second) ?

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

No built-in way to display time-of-day only, as of Vaadin 8.1.

You can make your own.

## Details

The existing `DateTimeField`]() widget supports only the legacy `GregorianCalendar` class which is a combination of a date *and* a time-of-day *plus* a time zone. So not useful for time-of-day only values.

Unfortunately, as of Vaadin 8.1, it seems the bundled field widgets have not yet been updated for the java.time types such as the [`java.time.LocalTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html) you would want.

As a workaround for the lack of an intelligent `LocalTime`-savvy field, I suggest either:

- Try the [*date-time-fields Add-on*](https://vaadin.com/directory/component/date-time-fields-add-on).
  An add-on is an extension you can add to your Vaadin project, to deliver some nugget of Vaadin-related functionality. An add-on may be visual widget related, or may be non-visual backend feature. If visual such as this, you may need to do a rebuild of your project to cause the widgetset to be re-created. Perhaps a Maven `clean` and `install` (not sure as the technique for this keeps changing with various Vaadin releases).
- Make your own. Use a regular text field. Write a validator to verify user input [parses](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html#parse-java.lang.CharSequence-java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter-) as a [`LocalTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html) object. You have a choice of writing a Vaadin-specific validator or a standard [*Bean Validation*](http://beanvalidation.org) validator. See [*How to add Validators in Vaadin 8*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42491883/642706)?

## Example

Here is some rough code for creating your own `LocalTime`-savvy field. This is by no means complete, but may help point you in the right direction.

```
final Label whenLabel = new Label( "when?" );
final TextField whenField = new TextField( );
whenField.setCaption( "When:" );
whenField.setValueChangeMode( ValueChangeMode.BLUR );
whenField.addValueChangeListener( new HasValue.ValueChangeListener < String >( )
{
    static final long serialVersionUID = 201710132100L;

    @Override
    public void valueChange ( HasValue.ValueChangeEvent < String > valueChangeEvent )
    {
        String input = whenField.getValue( );
        System.out.println( "input: " + input );
        try
        {
            // DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_TIME; // Constant ISO_LOCAL_TIME is for time-of-day in standard ISO 8601 format.
            // DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedTime( FormatStyle.SHORT ).withLocale( Locale.CANADA_FRENCH ); // Automatically localize.
            DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedTime( FormatStyle.SHORT ).withLocale( Locale.US ); // Automatically localize.
            LocalTime localTime = LocalTime.parse( input , f );
            String timeIso8601 = localTime.toString( );
            whenLabel.setValue( timeIso8601 );
        } catch ( DateTimeParseException e )
        {
            whenLabel.setValue( e.getClass().getCanonicalName() );
            System.out.println( "ERROR - failed to parse input: " + input );
        }
    }
} );
```

Answer (score 0):

In my solution I used a TextField and added a custom validator to the relevant binder:

```
.withValidator(this::validateTime, "Invalid time")
```

I implemented the validate method as follows:

```
private boolean validateTime(final String timeString) {

    try {
        LocalTime.parse(timeString);
        return true;
    } catch (final DateTimeParseException e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

now Vaadin 14.2.x provided new **DateTimePicker** component to solve this problem.

https://vaadin.com/releases/vaadin-14